# Email field required django.contrib.auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I want to register a user in django-rest-auth, if all username, password and email fields are provided. (I want to implement token authentication too to obtain a JSON response from the server.)

The default email field in `django.contrib.auth.User` is optional. But I want to set the email filed as required to register in the database so that the user gets an HTTP error response when a POST request has been made without an email.

In the project I am registering the new user through the following code.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', User.USERNAME_FIELD, "password", 'full_name',
                  'is_active', 'links', )
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("Validated Data",validated_data)
        if 'email' in validated_data:
            user = get_user_model().objects.create(
                username=validated_data['username']
            )
            user.set_email(validated_data['email'])
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'World',
                                 to=[validated_data['email']])
            email.send()
            user.is_active=False
            return user
        else:
            return None
```

However, the above gives:

> create() did not return an object instance

How do I set the email field as a required field?

Comment: Two things: the full traceback would have been incredibly useful, and the issue is that you are doing validation during `create` (and returning `None` because of it). You _must_ return a user object from the create method.

Comment: What do you mean by "full traceback"? Can you provide any documents regarding that. 
Later I am using the following line in UserSerializer.
     email=EmailField(required=True)
That way it is working. Is it correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to register an user in django-rest-auth, if all username, password and email fields are provided.

The correct way to require a field on a serializer in Django REST framework is to [set `required=True` when initializing the field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required), or [using the `extra_kwargs` parameter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) to set it on automatically generated fields.

> In default email field in django.contrib.auth.User is optional. But I want to set the email filed as required to register in the database so that the user gets HTTP error response when POST request has been made without a email.

This means that the automatically generated field will not be required by default, but you can still override it with `required=True`.

> However, the above gives:
>
> > create() did not return an object instance

This is because you are not returning a `User` instance from the `create` method, just like it says on the tin. Specifically, you are returning `None` if the `email` field is not included. `None` is not a `User` instance, and DRF is warning you that you're doing something wrong.